# NoSuchFieldException: versionID while trying to run a Yarn application

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

trying to replicate the Yarn tutorial from http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html.

It actually needed some modification to run on CDH4.3. It crashes as follows:

```
     13/12/02 17:09:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: versionID
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolVersion(RPC.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invocation.<init>(WritableRpcEngine.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:225)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
        at ch.unibe.scg.yarn.ApplicationMaster.launch(ApplicationMaster.java:58)
        at ch.unibe.scg.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.java:112)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: versionID
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolVersion(RPC.java:167)
        ... 5 more
```

Here's our code, up to the point where it crashes.

```
    // mostly stolen from http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path(CONF_FILE_PATH));
    YarnConfiguration yarnConf = new YarnConfiguration(conf);
    InetSocketAddress rmAddress = NetUtils.createSocketAddr(
            yarnConf.get(YarnConfiguration.RM_ADDRESS, YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_ADDRESS));     

    Configuration appsManagerServerConf = new Configuration(conf);
    ClientRMProtocol applicationsManager = RPC.getProxy(ClientRMProtocol.class, 1L, rmAddress, appsManagerServerConf);

    GetNewApplicationRequest request = Records.newRecord(GetNewApplicationRequest.class);             
    GetNewApplicationResponse response = applicationsManager.getNewApplication(request);
```

The last line there triggers the above exception.

Comment: too late to ask, but how did you solve this problem?